# Awk from a file

Tags: bash, awk

How do I use awk in a bash file?

I know how to do this on the command line with

```
awk `{...}`
```

But how do I do place this in a bash file.

This is what I'm doing right now

```
awk

Begin
{

    ...
}
{
    ...
}
END
{
   ...
}
```

What am I missing from the syntax?

Comment: Do you want to include the awk script in-line with the rest of the bash script, or call a separate script? The first is convenient for short awk scripts, whereas the second is better for things that are more complicated.

Comment: Right now, I'm trying to just include it inline in the bash script.

Comment: What error did you get ?

Comment: Something to the extent of: command not found.

Comment: I've got it to work if I place the blocks in quotes, keeping the first brace on the same line as the awk command.

Comment: @agentNil now I see what your problem was: you are using awk ` { ... } ` , whereas you need to use quotes: `awk '{ ... }'`.

Comment: No I tried it with quotes and it still resulted in errors. It was the problem I mentioned above.

Comment: OK, so it is about having `BEGIN` and `{` in the same line, as I also commented in my answer as per your question in comments there. You can mark as accepted if it helped.

Answer (score 3):

Just add it normally, such like this:

```
awk '...' file
```

Note that, instead, you were using

```
awk `{ ... }` file
```

Also note `BEGIN` and `END` blocks need the opening brace to be in the same line. Otherwise you will get an error like this:

> awk: cmd. line:2: BEGIN blocks must have an action part

Use `BEGIN`, not `Begin`.

---

See a complete working example:

```
$ cat a
#!/bin/bash

echo "we received file: $1"

awk 'BEGIN {print "-entering in awk script"}
     {print $1, $3}
     END {print "-that was it"}' $1
```

And this is the file we will provide:

```
$ cat b
hello this is a test
and this another text
```

And we execute it:

```
$ ./a b
we received file: b
-entering in awk script
hello is
and another
-that was it
```

Comment: I can do that but when I place the braces on seperate lines, it gives me an error.

Comment: @agentNil Have you put single quotes around the whole thing ?

Comment: @agentNil the `BEGIN` and `END` blocks have to contain `{}` in the same line. Otherwise you get the error: `awk: cmd. line:2: BEGIN blocks must have an action part`.

Comment: Pedantically, just the opening bracket needs to be on the same line.

Comment: @glennjackman It's not just being pedant, you mentioned an _useful_ feature. When you are placing your code in a file rater than trying it on the cli you may want to write one statement per line in the hope of increasing readability, maybe also interspersing comments.

Comment: But what if, what I want to add is can't fit easily on a single line.

Comment: @agentNil Please update your question with sample input and desired output. You can ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If the [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) script is complicated then you may create an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) script file and add run rights to it. Using **fedorqui**'s example the x.awk file could be like this:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {print "-entering in awk script"}
{print $1, $3}
END {print "-that was it"}
```

Then `chmod 700 x.awk` and then one can use x.awk as a normal utility:

```
#!/bin/bash
./x.awk input_file.txt
```

Comment: No need to `chmod`, etc. `awk` itself can handle it with: `awk -f x.awk input_file.txt`.

Comment: @fedorqui: You are right! In that case the `#!/bin/awk -f` also can be dropped. But I would prefer the runnable script version as it could be rewritten to `perl` (if the `awk` script become too complicated) without any modification in the caller script.

Comment: Yup! Also, I tend to use `chmod +x file` to give execution permission instead of explicitly `chmod 700`. But that just depends on each one. Anyway, +1!

Comment: @fedorqui: Thx! You are right again! Actually I prefer to use the explicit version as I'm good at counting with octal numbers. ;)

Comment: Why isn't there a way to write this on a multi line.

Comment: @agentNil: Could you explain what you mean? This solution written is in 5 lines.